# How do I create a node with a 64bit long property?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using cypher, something like:

```
MERGE (t:Test { tl: 10508455564958384115 })
```

that wouldn't return

```
integer is too large (line 1, column 21) "MERGE (t:Test { tl: 10508455564958384115 })" ^
```

but instead create the node with the value stored as long.

There's a [long](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/graphdb-neo4j-properties.html) property described in the manual, so I'm guessing this should work someway?

Comment: I should add that I'm interested in indexing this value afterwards, if possible.

Comment: AFAIK, `9223372036854775807` is the max limit. (*Don't know if it is correct, also try putting a `.0` at the end*)

Comment: @BhargavRao ah, you are correct. I guess I'll have to find a way to convert the number to signed 64bit in my host language

Comment: Hey, I also noticed that if you add `.0` at the end, it stores it as a `double`, but while displaying will ignore `.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10508455564958384115 is greater than the maximum value for a Java LONG which is
9223372036854775807

Use a string value instead, currently big-decimal values are not supported.